# Is it correct to say that $\mbox{span}(\mathcal{M}(\Xi^{N}))=\mbox{span}(\otimes_{i=1}^{N}\mathcal{M}(\Xi))?$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory, geometric-measure-theory, outer-measure

Let $(\Xi,\mathcal{E})$ be a measurable space, we denote $\mathcal{M}(\Xi)$ the set of all probability measures supported on $\Xi$. In an analogous way $\mathcal{M}(\Xi^{N})$ is the set of all probability measures supported on $\Xi^{N}$ where $(\Xi^{N},\mathcal{E}^{N})$ is measurable space with $\mathcal{E}^{N}$ as the product $\sigma$-algebra.

**Question:** If we denote $\mathcal{X}=\mbox{span}\left(\mathcal{M}(\Xi^{N})\right)$, is it correct to say that
$$ \mathcal{X}=\mbox{span}\left(\mathcal{M}(\Xi^{N})\right)=\mbox{span}\left(\mathcal{M}(\Xi)^{N}\right)=\mbox{span}\left(\otimes_{i=1}^{N}\mathcal{M}(\Xi)\right)?$$
Furthermore, if we denote $\mbox{cone}(S)$ as the cone generated by the set $S$, then  is it correct to say that
$$\mathcal{C}:=\mbox{cone}\left(\mathcal{M}(\Xi^{N}) \right)=\mbox{cone}\left(\mathcal{M}(\Xi)^{N} \right)=\mbox{cone}\left(\otimes_{i=1}^{N}\mathcal{M}(\Xi) \right)?$$

Comment: Do you mean the closure of the span?

Comment: @fourierwho No, actually $\mathcal{X}$ is the space of signaled measures generated by $\mathcal{M}(\Xi^{N})$. I think as I am writing it is correct.

Comment: You are asking if every signed measure on $\Xi^N$ is a finite linear combination of product measures - why would you expect this to be true?